# To apply L'Hôpital's Rule to the ratio which consists of the integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

Let us remember, the conditions to apply L'Hôpital's Rule:

Let suppose:

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are real and differentiable  for all $x\in (a,b)$

1-) $ \lim_{x\to c}{f(x)} = \lim_{x\to c}g(x) = 0$

2-)  If $g'(x)\neq 0$  $,\,\,\,\,$  as on some deleted neighborhood of $\,\,$ $c$.

3-)  $\,\,\,\,\,$  $\lim_{x\to c}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}} = L$, then

4-)  $\lim_{x\to c}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}=L$, $\,\,\,\,\,$ thus we can write:

$$ \lim_{x\to c}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}=\lim_{x\to c}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}} = L $$

**Note 1:** I have written all the above information just to remember to L'Hôpital's Rule. They are not related with my question. If I wrote something as incorect, you can correct it inside of the question.

$$-----------$$
ANYWAY, Let us suppose that our following example satisfies the conditions to apply L'Hôpital's Rule  which we stated above. If we start:

$\lim_{u\to \infty}\int_0^u F(t,a)dt=0$ $\,\,\,$  and$\,\,\,\,\,$  $\lim_{u\to \infty}\int_0^u G(t,a)dt=0$

$$\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{ \int_0^u F(t,a) \, dt}{\int_0^u G(t,a) \, dt} $$

THE QUESTION. **Before** to apply L'Hôpital's Rule with respect to the parameter $´u´$ to the above-equation, do we need to also **to prove** the following one?

There exists a number $M$ as $M> 0$.

The denominator $\,\,$  $\int_0^u G(t,a)dt$ $\,\,$ should **not** equal to zero for any$\,\,\,\,$ $u > M$.

**Note 2:** Please aware I am **not asking** anything about $\,\,$ $ \frac{d}{du} {\int_0^u G(t,a) \, dt}$

Answer (score 1):

Condition 2 needs two tweaks.  The first is that it doesn't make sense if $c$ is infinity.  Second, you don't need the denominator to be nonzero in the entire deleted neighborhood, but only in some neighborhood of $c.$

If you have a notion of "neighborhood of infinity," you can rewrite your condition as

2)  There is a deleted neighborhood about $c$ over which $g'(x)$ is nonzero.

Since you have $u\to \infty$, you need only that $G(u,a)$ (and it integral) are nonzero for all $u$ greater that some constant $M$.

There's another glitch in that your question seems to be about condition 2) which is about the derivative of the denominator, but when you get to your final question, you don't ask about the derivative(?)

Comment: Okay please forget $g'(x)$. Yes, you are right, I am not asking the derivative?  Now, can I take your answer again for my main question only.

Comment: I am asking $\int_0^u G(t,a)dt$ $\,\,$ cannot equal to zero for any$\,\,\,\,$ $u > 0$. But you speak $G(u,a)$. Can I take your comment again , please?

Comment: We have recently discussed with one friend. He says:  L’Hopital’s rule for the limit as $u->\infty$ of $\int_0^u F(t,a)dt$/$\int_0^u G(t,a)dt$ has 2 requirements:

(1) There exists a number $M > 0$ such that $\int_0^u F(t,a)dt$ and $\int_0^u G(t,a)dt$ are each differentiable for all $u > M$.

(2) $\int_0^u G(t,a)dt$ cannot equal zero for any $u > M$.

Is he right ?

Comment: Yes.  The $M>0$ is the "neighborhood of infinity."  The denominator can be zero a few times, but eventually it has to stop.

Comment: Dear Goddard , please note do we have to prove before to apply L’Hopital’s rule the following condition?  $\int_0^{u}G(t,a)dt$ should not equal to zero for any  $u>M>0$.  My friend say if you can not prove it, you can not apply.  On the other hand,  you wrote just a few minutes ago **The denominator can be zero a few times**  .  I have never said anything about it.  How can you say it ? The denominator can be zero a few times  **or never be zero ,  of course except on the infinity **

Comment: The denominator has to be nonzero from some point (which I'm calling $M$) on.  As long as you can find a point, after which the denominator is never zero, then you can apply L'hospital.

Comment: Dear Goddard , I kindly request from you, please look the question again  and **give your last comment**.  Thank you.

Comment: Now I have understood you more perfectly. My friend (which I had discussed) ) was wrong.  You said :  **you don't need the denominator to be nonzero in the entire deleted neighborhood, but only in some neighborhood of c.

If you have a notion of "neighborhood of infinity," you can rewrite your condition**     Thus ,  I can define "neighborhood of infinity," as: A neighborhood of  $+∞$  is a subset of the set of real numbers  $ℝ$  which contains an interval ($M,+∞)$  for some $M∈ℝ$. That is, a subset which contains all sufficiently large real numbers. Thus we will consider here only for $u>M$

Answer (score 1):

The crucial issue here is the question of whether or not L'Hôpital's rule is applicable if all hypotheses are met except the possibility that $g'(x)$ can equal zero somewhere.

> Where L'Hôpital's rule can fail -- for limits as $x \to +\infty$ -- is
>   if for any $c > 0$ there exists $x_c > c$ such that $g'(x_c) = 0$.

A common misconception is that this is solely because the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ cannot be defined if $g'(x)$ is zero infinitely often. This is not true because there can arise situations where $g'(x) = f'(x) h(x)$ with (1) $g'(x) = 0$ infinitely often, and (2) $h(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$, such that the limit of the ratio of derivatives can exist, i.e.,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{f'(x)h(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{h(x)}, $$

but $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/g(x) $ can fail to exist.

As an example, take

$$f(x) = \left(\int_0^x \cos^2 t \, dt \right)^{-1}, \quad g(x) = f(x) e^{\sin x}$$

Here we have $f(x), g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, and

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^{\sin x}} \quad \text{DNE} $$

However,

$$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \frac{-(f(x))^2 \cos^2x}{{-(f(x))^{2} \cos^2x \,e^{\sin x} + f(x) e^{\sin x} \cos x}} = \frac{\cos x}{e^{\sin x}(\cos x - (f(x))^{-1}) }$$

Since $e^{\sin x}$ is bounded between $e^{-1}$ and $e$ and $(f(x))^{-1} \to \infty$, we have

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = 0$$

Hence,  L'Hôpital's rule fails here.  This is attributable to the fact that $g'(x)$ has the factor $\cos x$ which is zero for all $x= x_n = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi$.

Comment: dear friend ,thank you very much for your detail answer. However, please look at it again,  **my question is simple and  different**. Thus, I can not see the answer of it on your study.

Comment: To keep notation simple I am discussing a limit as it applies to $\frac{f(u)}{g(u)}$. To correspond to your notation take $f(u) = \int_0^u F(t,a) \, dt$ and $g(u) = \int_0^u G(t,a) \, dt$.  There is nothing special about these integrals as it pertains to your question.  Assuming that there is no issue here, it seems you changed the  focus of your question on zeros of $g(u)$ rather than $g'(u)$. It is somewhat of the same story as what I discussed in my answer.

Comment: Yes -- as long as there exists $M>0$ such that $g(u) \neq 0$ (as well as $g'(u) \neq 0$) for all $u > M$ then you can safely apply L'Hopital's rule if all the other conditions are met.  In the case of $g(u)$ it is more a question of whether $\lim_{u \to \infty} f(u)/g(u)$ could even exist if the denominator could attain a value of $0$ infinitely often as $u \to \infty$ and where $f(u)/g(u)$ is not defined at those points.  The condition is stated in most books so that this question cannot even come up.

Comment: Dear RRL,  thank you very much.  Now I have gotten my reply in your second comment firmly. Thank you again. Thus , the reply is :  **YES, it means , we have to proove that  the denominator should not equal to zero many times in my question for all $u >M$  which $M >0$   **

Comment: Dear RRL,   I am very confused again . Now, if there is a possibility , for example as if  the denominator $\,\,$  $\int_0^{100} G(t,a)dt=0$ $\,\,$   ,  will  we not apply L'hospital rule to the equation in my question ?  But of course , do not forget please, I am looking the limit at the infinity.

Comment: Dear RRL , for  $M> 0$.

we know  any$\,\,\,\,$ $u > M$.       $\,\,$ $ \frac{d}{du} {\int_0^u G(t,a) \, dt}≠0$ .  I mean $\,\,$ $ G(u,a)≠0$

Comment: Dear RRL, $\,\,$ On the other hand,  we know that  there is no any  possibility  for sufficiently large "u" values that  the denominator  can not equal zero, 
 for example $\,\,$  $\int_0^{10^{100}} G(t,a)dt≠0$ $\,\,$ . Thus, can we apply L'hospital rule to the equation in my question ?  But of course, do not forget please, I am looking the limit at the infinity.